# curlimages/curl no longer supports arm64?

Tags: docker, curl, dockerhub

rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"docker.io/curlimages/curl:latest\": no match for platform in manifest: not found""

Looks like curlimages no longer supports arm64? My poor pis.

No mention here - https://github.com/curl/curl-docker/issues

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is an issue here: https://github.com/curl/curl-container/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this issue. We fixed the issue by building our own image with the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
```